# acm sig-alternate.cls right margin smaller than left

Tags: paper-size

i downloaded the Tighter Alternate style file and tex from http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates

but when i download the style file and tex file and compile it at on my computer,  the right side margin appears smaller than the left margin.

[image]
but the site shows a perfect one

http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.pdf

i didn't do any changes to the style sheet. Can someone please help me.

Comment: what size paper are you printing on (the acm sample pdf is on US letter paper 8.5in by 11in) if you print on A4 the margins will look wrong but it doesn't matter as it'll be OK on the final paper.

Comment: I have no idea about texniccenter but if you view the pdf that you are generating in any pdf viewer you can usually look at the document properties and see what page size it is.

Comment: thanks David, Miktex had it set to A4. i changed it to Letter. and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins are correct for US letter paper. It's OK for drafting on A4 as the text block will be correct but not ideally positioned. You should be able to specify letter size in the latex file or in the options for your dvi driver.